# Firebase rules for storage are not working (no permission to accesss)

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

**THE UPLOADING PART WORKS WITH NO PROBLEMS**

This is my code for uploading the png/jpg files to firebase storage, and then getting it back as a url to it.

```
let userId = auth?.currentUser?.uid;

  const uploadImage = () => {
    if (imgUpload === null) return;

  //Upload Part

const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${userId}/${imgUpload.name + v4()}`);
    uploadBytes(imageRef, imgUpload).then(() => {

   //Getting url back so i can use it in image part

   getDownloadURL(imageRef).then((url) => {
        console.log(`Message sent to database: ${url}`);
        setImgUrl(url);
        setChecker("image");
        alert("Image uploaded");
      });
    });
  };
```

**This is the link where my file that user is uploading is stored**

gs://appname-c0588.appspot.com/images/AmaxuDQIidaTmVCV5fKs0SdeBtf1/Icon_Bird_512x512.png

**This is what the getDwonloadURL is requesting**

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/appname-c0588.appspot.com/o/images%2FAmaxuDQIidaTmVCV5fKs0SdeBtf1%2FIcon_Bird_512x512.png

**this is the rules in storage**

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/{userId}/{fileName} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                          && request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024
                          && (request.resource.contentType.matches('image/jpeg')
                              || request.resource.contentType.matches('image/png'));
    }
  }
}
```

Error I am receiving after submitting ( uploading works fine, but it's connected into one method with receiving it back)

Error getting download URL: FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'images/AmaxuDQIidaTmVCV5fKs0SdeBtf1/Icon_Bird_512x512.png'. (storage/unauthorized)

I also console.logged userId when submitting, and it is the same so "AmaxuDQIidaTmVCV5fKs0SdeBtf1"

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow works like a charm

fixed it:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/{userId}/{fileName} {
      // Allow write if conditions are met
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                  && request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024
                  && (request.resource.contentType.matches('image/jpeg')
                      || request.resource.contentType.matches('image/png'));

      // Allow read when request.auth.email is not null
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

I was wondering, why am I having this problem, and as I was guessing, it was my lack of basic understanding of firebase rules writing.

The problem was that the reading also checked if

```
&& request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024
                          && (request.resource.contentType.matches('image/jpeg')
                              || request.resource.contentType.matches('image/png'));
```

and now read and write are two seperate checks